# Eratosthenes prime numbers

Tags: c

I have created a program to search for prime numbers. It works without problems until the entered number is smaller than 52, when it is bigger output prints out some blank (0) numbers and I don't know why. Also other numbers have blank output.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Prime numbers
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int c[100], n, a[50], d, e, b = 1;

void sort() {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (c[i] > 1) {
            a[b] = c[i];
            printf("%d %d %d\n", a[1], b, i);
            b++;
            e = 2;
            d = 0;
            while (d <= n) {
                d = c[i] * e;
                c[d - 1] = 0;
                e++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter number as an limit:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = i + 1;
    }
    sort();
    printf("Prime numbers between 1 and %d are:\n", n);
    for (int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is output for `25`:

```
Enter number as an limit:
25
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 4
2 4 6
2 5 10
2 6 12
2 7 16
2 8 18
2 9 22
Prime numbers between 1 and 25 are:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
```

But for `83` is:

```
Enter number as an limit:
83
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 4
2 4 6
2 5 10
2 6 12
2 7 16
2 8 18
2 9 22
2 10 28
2 11 30
2 12 36
2 13 40
2 14 42
2 15 46
2 16 52
0 17 58
0 18 60
0 19 66
0 20 70
0 21 72
0 22 78
0 23 82
Prime numbers between 1 and 83 are:
0 3 5 7 11 0 17 19 23 29 31 37 0 43 47 53 0 61 67 71 73 79 83
```

Blank spots always spots after 17th prime number. And always the blank numbers are the same. Can you help me please what is the problem?

Comment: `d = c[i] * e;` will set `d` to 53*2 or 106, then `c[d - 1] = 0;` attempts to write to an non-existent array position.

Comment: Did you check whether you ever access beyond bounds of arrays? If you have problems at 52, I'd not be surprised if you access beyond 50 in array `a`. By the way, debugging gets easier (for us and for you) if you use speaking variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It makes sense, it is working right now. I expected array[50] to be able to keep 50 numbers and not number with size 50 or less. Next time i will change variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop setting entries in `c` for multiples of `c[i]` runs too far: you should compute the next `d` **before** comparing against `n`:

```
        for (d = c[i] * 2; d <= n; d += c[i]) {
            c[d - 1] = 0;
        }
```

As a matter of fact you could start at `d = c[i] * c[i]` because all lower multiples have already been seen during the previous iterations of the outer loop.

Also note that it is confusing to store `i + 1` into `c[i]`: the code would be simpler with an array of booleans holding `1` for prime numbers and `0` for composite.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char c[101];
    int a[50];
    int n, b = 0;

    printf("Enter number as a limit:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 100) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (c[i] != 0) {
            a[b] = i;
            //printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], b, i);
            b++;
            for (int d = i * i; d <= n; d += i) {
                c[d] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Prime numbers between 1 and %d are:\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
chqrlie$ ./sieve4780
Enter number as a limit:
25
Prime numbers between 1 and 25 are:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
chqrlie$ ./sieve4780
Enter number as a limit:
83
Prime numbers between 1 and 83 are:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79
```

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understand correctly, i would change whole while loop with your for loop, because d+=c[i] means that after d=c[i]*2 will d+=c[i] enter the value of c[i]*2 into d. If c[i] was 2 it means it is c[i] squared, so  2 4 8 16 and i miss 6 10 12 ... (sorry for not understanding but I am only beginner)

Comment: The goal of this loop is set all multiples of `c[i]` as composite numbers, so starting from `d = c[i] * 2` and adding `c[i]` to `d` after each iteration as long as `d` is less or equal to `n`. You can start from `c[i] * c[i]` because all lesser multiples of `c[i]` are multiples of a smaller prime number too, thus have already been enumerated for a previous prime.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be caused by the fact that you have declared an array with size 50, but in fact it goes further than that: imagine you want to use Eratosthenes' procedure to find the first 10,000 prime numbers. Does this mean that you need to declare an array of size 10,000 first (or even bigger), risking to blow up your memory?

No: best thing to do is to work with collections where you don't need to set the maximum size at declaration time, like a linked list, a vector, ..., like that you can make your list grow as much as you like during runtime.

Comment: it looks like it is tagged C, not C++

Comment: The array `a` holds the prime numbers. 50 is actually plenty since there are only 25 prime numbers between 1 and 100. The OP should just check that `n` is `> 0` and `<= 100`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am only beginner and option with unlimited size is new for me. I am going to search :D

Comment: @JurajŽilt: in case you're working with C (not C++), linked lists might be what you're looking for (vectors are C++ technology).